# Cannot select pass the first <td> element with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I am trying to do an onclick delete on selected dynamic  elements but for some reason it only selects the first  element every time.

```
// Function to delete entries
$("#timesheet").on('click', '.delRow', function () {
    const firstUrl = "API LINK..."
    const secondUrl = document.getElementById("timesheetDetailsID").innerText
    console.log(secondUrl)
    const settings = {
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": JSON.stringify(firstUrl + secondUrl),
        "method": "DELETE",
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "processData": false,
        success: function () {
            alert("Yay")
        },
        error: function () {
            //error handler
            alert("Boo")
        }
    };
    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
});
```

Example of the HTML page:
[Example of the HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PYy0.png)

```
//Dynamic HTML 
const htmlTemplate = `
    <tr id = "testDeleteTimesheet">
      <td>${entry.hours}</td>
<td id = "timesheetDetailsID" style = "display: none;">${entry.timesheetDetailsId}</td>
      <td>${chartDate}</td>
      <td>${entry.contractCode}</td>
      <td>${entry.activityCode}</td>
      <td>${entry.otFlag}</td>
      <td>${entry.notes}</td>
      

<td><button id=\"edit-" + counter + "\" class=\"btn editRow btnStyle btn-primary btn-sm\"><span class=\ "bi bi-pencil\"></span></button> 
<button id=\"delete-" + counter + "\" class=\"btn delRow btnStyle btn-danger btn-sm\"><span class=\"bi bi-eraser\"></span></button></td>
    </tr>
    `;
```

This is my static html where the dynamic content targets

```
//.html page
 <table class="table" id="timesheet">
     <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Hours</th>
          <th scope="col">Date</th>
          <th scope="col">ContractCode</th>
          <th scope="col">Activity Code</th>
          <th scope="col">OT</th>
          <th scope="col">Notes</th>
          <th scope="col" id="rowBtns"></th>
        </tr>
   </thead>
<tbody id="tsdata"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "only selects the first element"?  What is your HTML, and specifically what operation in this code is producing an unexpected result?

Comment: You need to share HTML for a better answer. But what I believe is that you are selecting components having duplicate id values. You should select by class name and see if it works for you.

Comment: You are calling `$("#timesheet")` which is the element with `id="timesheet"`. An id needs to be assigned to only one element. So if you have multiple elements with the same ID, the jQuery will only bring back the first one it finds.

Comment: @Steve timesheet is on the .html file that is the wrapper of all the dynamic <td>

Comment: @Zurez sorry I just updated the question with my html.

Comment: In your dynamic html, every `<tr>` as an ID of `testDeleteTimesheet` and every second `<td>`  has the same ID of `timesheetDetailsID`. Make sure that your ID's are all unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are re-using the same `id` value multiple times in your HTML.  If you have multiple elements with `id="timesheetDetailsID"` then which element do you expect `document.getElementById("timesheetDetailsID")` to return and why?  Since IDs are supposed to be unique, the browser stops looking when it finds one.

Use a `class` instead of an `id`:

```
<tr class="testDeleteTimesheet">
  <td>${entry.hours}</td>
  <td class="timesheetDetailsID" style="display: none;">${entry.timesheetDetailsId}</td>
  <!-- etc. -->
```

Then in your click handler, traverse the DOM from `$(this)` to find the element you want for that specific row:

```
const secondUrl = $(this).closest('tr.testDeleteTimesheet').find('td.timesheetDetailsID').text();
```

This will start at the clicked element, use `.closest()` to traverse up to the parent `<tr>` element, then use `.find()` to traverse back down to the intended `<td>` element, then get that element's text.

Comment: I just tried using your method but the second url comes back as blank I'm not sure why

Comment: @Gabe: [Works for me.](https://jsfiddle.net/ojnwz87h/)  Can you demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Terribly sorry it was a mistake on my part that caused it to not work. Your code worked great! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

If you have more timesheets, you have to use class instead ID.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a working example:

```js
const data = [{
    hours: 8,
    timesheetDetailsId: '/url/1',
    contractCode: 'NT/00008',
    activityCode: 'TEST',
    otFlag: false,
    notes: 'Test Test Test'
  },
  {
    hours: 8,
    timesheetDetailsId: '/url/2',
    contractCode: 'NT/00008',
    activityCode: 'TEST',
    otFlag: false,
    notes: 'Test Test Test'
  },
  {
    hours: 8,
    timesheetDetailsId: '/url/3',
    contractCode: 'NT/00008',
    activityCode: 'TEST',
    otFlag: false,
    notes: 'Test Test Test'
  },
  {
    hours: 8,
    timesheetDetailsId: '/url/1',
    contractCode: 'NT/00008',
    activityCode: 'TEST',
    otFlag: false,
    notes: 'Test Test Test'
  },
  {
    hours: 8,
    timesheetDetailsId: '/url/4',
    contractCode: 'NT/00008',
    activityCode: 'TEST',
    otFlag: false,
    notes: 'Test Test Test'
  },

];

const chartDate = '1-Sep-2021';
let counter = 0;


data.forEach(entry => {
  counter++;
  const htmlTemplate = `
<tr id = "testDeleteTimesheet">
    <td>${entry.hours}</td>
    <td class="timesheetDetailsID" style = "display: none;">${entry.timesheetDetailsId}</td>
    <td>${chartDate}</td>
    <td>${entry.contractCode}</td>
    <td>${entry.activityCode}</td>
    <td>${entry.otFlag}</td>
    <td>${entry.notes}</td>
    <td>
      <button id="edit-${counter}" class="btn editRow btnStyle btn-primary btn-sm">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-pencil" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path d="M12.146.146a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l3 3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-10 10a.5.5 0 0 1-.168.11l-5 2a.5.5 0 0 1-.65-.65l2-5a.5.5 0 0 1 .11-.168l10-10zM11.207 2.5 13.5 4.793 14.793 3.5 12.5 1.207 11.207 2.5zm1.586 3L10.5 3.207 4 9.707V10h.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v.5h.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v.5h.293l6.5-6.5zm-9.761 5.175-.106.106-1.528 3.821 3.821-1.528.106-.106A.5.5 0 0 1 5 12.5V12h-.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5V11h-.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.468-.325z"/>
        </svg>
      </button> 
      <button id="delete-${counter}" class="btn delRow btnStyle btn-danger btn-sm">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-eraser" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path d="M8.086 2.207a2 2 0 0 1 2.828 0l3.879 3.879a2 2 0 0 1 0 2.828l-5.5 5.5A2 2 0 0 1 7.879 15H5.12a2 2 0 0 1-1.414-.586l-2.5-2.5a2 2 0 0 1 0-2.828l6.879-6.879zm2.121.707a1 1 0 0 0-1.414 0L4.16 7.547l5.293 5.293 4.633-4.633a1 1 0 0 0 0-1.414l-3.879-3.879zM8.746 13.547 3.453 8.254 1.914 9.793a1 1 0 0 0 0 1.414l2.5 2.5a1 1 0 0 0 .707.293H7.88a1 1 0 0 0 .707-.293l.16-.16z"/>
        </svg>
      </button>
    </td>
</tr>`;

  $(`#tsdata`).append(htmlTemplate)
})

$(`.delRow`).on(`click`, function(){
  const tr = $(this).closest(`tr`);
  const timesheetDetailsID = tr.find(`.timesheetDetailsID`);
  console.log(timesheetDetailsID.text())
  tr.remove();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table class="table" id="timesheet">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Hours</th>
      <th scope="col">Date</th>
      <th scope="col">ContractCode</th>
      <th scope="col">Activity Code</th>
      <th scope="col">OT</th>
      <th scope="col">Notes</th>
      <th scope="col" id="rowBtns"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tsdata"></tbody>
</table>
```